# How to make this plastic material?

Tags: materials

I'm creating an NES controller, and I'm stuck at making a realistic material for the controller body. 
How do you achieve it?[image]

Comment: Try googling plastic material cycles (assuming you want to use cycles). There are a bunch of hits. You can also find a model containing plastic on a site like blendswap, download it and use the materials. Mind the licence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this way: Mix a *Diffuse* with a *Glossy*, with a *Fresnel* as *Factor*, maybe add a *Subsurface Scattering* to give a bit of translucency, and also a *Noise* to give a grainy relief to the surfaces. Change the color and the *Noise Scal*e and *Strength* depending on the part.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked.